# Ubuntu 20.04 mate marco hard coded key binding

Tags: key-bindings, mate, ubuntu-20.04

I use ubuntu 20.04 with mate (then marco). Up to now (pre-20.04) I could bind Mod4+S to my liking (Win+S). After 20.04 upgrade I discover that this Key shortcut Mod4+S is kinda 'hard-coded' to run mate-search-tool, and my explicit binding from [ControlCenter][Keyboard shortcuts] is not honored (ignored).

The problem exhibit itself as marco spitting the following message

"Failed to execute child process mate-search-tool (No such file or directory)"

Or if I install mate-utils (that I don't need) it run mate-search-tool.

I double checked the decong editor (gsettings) for any hidden 'run-command' mapped on key Mod4+S key but could  not find any.

So at the moment I call it an hard-coded key binding.

I'd like to bind Mod4+S, any pointers appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The key seems to be /org/mate/marco/keybinding-commands/command-6.
I didn't find a way to completely disable it but at least if I set the command I want in place of mate-search-tool it works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks, there are multiple keybindings in mate which are not exposed in control center / keyboard shortcuts config. For me, most of them are unwanted. To change or remove them install `dconf-editor` and go to `/org/mate/marco/global-keybindings/` path, where you can find multiple `run-command-X` keys. To disable them just set `disabled` string instead of existing keybinding.